# Ionic Application, book like structure

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I am currently developing an application for a personal side project in ionic. 
I've been looking for a module of some sort, which will let me use a single page swipe function, to create a book like structure.

I haven't been able to find any suitable modules for this.
I'd like to create pages by requesting text, and then filling the pages with the given text.

Any suggestions as to what i could use to achieve my goal? doesn't have to be ionic specific

Comment: `ion-slide-box` does not fit your needs?

Comment: It does to some extend, yet i wanted the the flip page effect for the look and feel